# Grabbing timestamp of every keystroke in a HIT

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk, boto3

I am creating an HIT that will display an image and a textbox. I want to log the timestamp of every keypress in the textfield in a list or other data structure, and have that information when reviewing the HIT response as well. Currently, I am using boto to write the HIT.

Here is my current code:

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.question import (QuestionContent,Question,QuestionForm, Overview,AnswerSpecification,SelectionAnswer,FormattedContent,FreeTextAnswer)

ACCESS_ID ='****************'
SECRET_KEY = '******************'
HOST = 'mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com'

mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                  host=HOST)

title = 'Give your feelings about a picture'
description = ('View a picture and give us your opinion on the image.')
keywords = 'image, comments, opinions'

#---------------  BUILD OVERVIEW -------------------

overview = Overview()
overview.append_field('Title', 'Type what you think about this picture!')
overview.append(FormattedContent('<img src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/mountain/mountain-03.jpg" '
                                 ' alt="Mountain" '
                                 ' height="40" '
                                 ' width="40"/>'))


#---------------  BUILD QUESTION 1 -------------------

qc2 = QuestionContent()
qc2.append_field('Title','Your Comments')

fta2 = FreeTextAnswer()

q2 = Question(identifier="comments",
              content=qc2,
              answer_spec=AnswerSpecification(fta2))

#--------------- BUILD THE QUESTION FORM -------------------

question_form = QuestionForm()
question_form.append(overview)
question_form.append(q2)

#--------------- CREATE THE HIT -------------------

mtc.create_hit(questions=question_form,
               max_assignments=1,
               title=title,
               description=description,
               keywords=keywords,
               duration = 60,
               reward=0.05)
```

I really have no clue where to start, as I only know how to log keystroke timestamps with jQuery. I have no prior experience with the Mechanical Turk API and everything I've written so far has been based off a tutorial. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can submit an HTMLQuestion HIT rather than the QuestionForm structure. With HTMLQuestion you can run arbitrary javascript. I'm not sure how to do this in boto, though.

Comment: I'll look into it! Thanks for the suggestion.